# How to do with the dialog that can insert data into arraylist

Tags: android

I was newbie in android and i try to use a dialog that prompt user a textfield to insert some data into my arraylist.
i face the the problem with in java class that related to getActivity,since i only extend activity with my java class

this is my XML

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:background="#FFFFBB33"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/insert"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:hint="@string/ItemName" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my java class

```
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
      // Get the layout inflater
      LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

      // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
      // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
      builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null))
      // Add action buttons
             .setPositiveButton(R.string.Insert, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     // sign in the user ...
                 }
             })
             .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                 }
             });      
      return builder.create();
  }
```

Comment: this is not java class, it's a method. what's the problem?

Comment: put your error log here.

Comment: the getactivity() was undefined by the mainactivity since my mainactivity extend with activity only

Answer (score 0):

`getActivity()` is only intended to classes that extend  `Fragment`  instead for an application that extend `Activity` you should use. 
`getApplication()`  / 
`getApplicationContext`   etc.

Comment: How if i insist to extend activity in my main activity,what should i do with the dialog

Comment: What do u mean by extending an activity in your main activity?? I assume it is extending the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

instead of,

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

Comment: but my                                                            LayoutInflater inflater = getApplication().getLayoutInflater();      has occur problem,and i didt clear with the dialogfragment

Answer (score 0):

You need an activity context for displaying dialogs. The application context suggested by some other answers won't work.

In an activity, use `this` to refer to the activity. In case the code is in an inner class, use `YourActivityName.this` to scope it to the outer class instance.

Comment: it work,but i have another problem that is with my cancel button in my dialog       .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                      DialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                  }
              });

Comment: When the button click handler runs, the dialog is already dismissed. No need to do cancel it there.

Comment: what u mean it is just ignore  DialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel(); ? and let it blank inside the onclick function

Comment: Yes, you don't need it there.